# How to add entry for bootable external drive partition to internal bootloader?

Tags: boot, partition, python, grub

I created a bootable partion on a Toshiba Canvio 2 for LinuxMint, leaving one other partition of same size for possibly another install in the future and the rest of the drive is for storage and back up. It works beautifully and I am quite happy with it. On my internal drive I have a dual boot , Win 7 and Fedora 22.

When I boot up my machine it goes straight to grub where I can choose Windows or Fedora. Choosing Windows then sends me on to the Windows bootloader and from there on to Windows (chain boot?). To boot into my external I must hit F12 for boot options. I wind up in grub where I can choose Mint, Fedora, and Win7. ( I created the boot partition on the external at the front of the disk )

This entire thing was for me to learn and understand creating partitions for swap, root, home, boot all on my own trying to understand the process. 
My question is this - say I want to have the option of booting into my external from the main grub screen , what would I have done differently? And what would I do now to change it?

Comment: You just need to give the path to the kernel and initrd in your external drive to the GRUB in your internal drive. I can't provide a full answer since I don't know GRUB2 configuration well.

Comment: With what you've provided for an answer I believe some google searching may get me what I need. I just don't want to break it, because like I said, it works great and I am very happy with it. But if there is a simple way, I would like to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works in case of Ubuntu. Commands might be slightly different in fedora (sorry, I am not a fedora guy!) but this will give you a general idea.

You have to edit the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file and add the following entry. So, open the `40_custom` file by:

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

and add the following entry right after the last line.

```
menuentry "Linux-Mint" {
        insmod chain
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd1'
        chainloader +1
}
```

Here. `hd1` is the drive containing bootable media. It can be different for you, so you have to get this number right or this will not work.

Save and close. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you restart your computer you'll see an entry named `Linux-Mint`.